# spinner expanding beyond screen bounds

Tags: android, width, spinner, tablelayout, stretch

I have a layout that contains a TableLayout with three rows.  Each row has a TextView and a Spinner.  The Spinners' column is set to stretch.  My problem is that the Spinners are stretching off the edge of the screen when they contain a long string.  I would like them to truncate the string instead.  Here's a screenshot of the problem:

http://www.comicfanboy.net/images/screenshot.png

and here's the xml for the layout:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/settings_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingLeft="3dp" android:paddingRight="3dp">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/general_information_defaults" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></TextView>
        <TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:stretchColumns="1">
            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="right|center_vertical" android:text="Spinner Label 1"></TextView>
                <Spinner android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/default_organization_spinner" android:layout_width="wrap_content"></Spinner>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="right|center_vertical" android:text="Spinner Label 2"></TextView>
                <Spinner android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/default_sport_spinner"></Spinner>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView android:id="@+id/TextView02" android:gravity="right|center_vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="Spinner Label 3"></TextView>
                <Spinner android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/default_injury_spinner"></Spinner>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/TextView03" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/email_defaults" android:paddingTop="20dp"></TextView>
        <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TableLayout01" android:stretchColumns="1">
            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TableRow02">
                <TextView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/TextView04" android:gravity="right|center_vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="@string/to"></TextView>
                <EditText android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/default_to_field">
                    <requestFocus></requestFocus>
                </EditText>
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/TableRow01">
                <TextView android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/TextView06" android:gravity="right|center_vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:text="@string/cc"></TextView>
                <EditText android:inputType="textEmailAddress" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/default_cc_field"></EditText>
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>
        <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/TextView05" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/program_options" android:paddingTop="20dp"></TextView>
        <CheckBox android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:paddingLeft="40dp" android:id="@+id/auto_sync_checkbox" android:text="@string/auto_sync_at_login"></CheckBox>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android:layout_width="100dip"` Use this tag in the spinner.

Comment: That was my first thought as well, but it doesn't have any effect.  The Spinners still stretch off the screen.

Comment: That works...it even works if I make it something really small like 5dp.  I would have thought setting a specific width like that would make it not stretch to fill the width of the screen if the screen was wider than the width I gave the spinner, but it looks like it's stretching how I want.  Why is that?

Comment: god knows.. Android itself is a mystery some times..:)

Comment: If I set it to a value larger than the screen, like 500dp, then it does stretch off the screen like I would expect.  I think maybe it has to do with the spinners being in the stretched column of the TableLayout.  It looks like as long as I set it to a width smaller than the screen, it works how I want.  I just set them all to 1dp and it works fine.

Answer (score 8):

For the spinner:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

This helped me.

Comment: This helped me too, but it should be: android:layout_weight="1"