# Android Spinner width in TableRow is constant

Tags: android, width, spinner

I have the following layout:

```
   <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/contentRow3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/hotelapp_textblack"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:text="@string/check_room"
            tools:context=".MainActivity" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinRoom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:dropDownWidth="match_parent" />

    </TableRow>
```

With the following ArrayAdapter layout:

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="30dp"
    android:textColor="#000" />
```

The `TableRow` is obviously one amongst many. The issue which I am facing here is that no matter what I do, I cannot change the width of the `Spinner`. (Not the list items, the spinner itself). So, regardless of whether I set the width to `0dp`, `match_parent`, `wrap_content` or `x_dp`, it stays the same. What do I have to do to modify the width?

Comment: By default a `TableRow` uses special `LayoutParams` for its children. Did you tried putting the `Spinner` in another layout(basically wrapping it with another layout) and that layout in the `Spinner`s position in the `TableRow`?

Comment: I have just tried doing so with a `LinearLayout`. The behaviour is rather weird. If `match_parent` is set, the Spinner "overflows" its LinearLayout, as if TableRow were its parent. If `wrap_content` is set, the `Spinner` shrinks, but it is still constant.

Comment: The `TableLayout` does have some problems(not only with that `Spinner`). One thing to try as an ugly hack would be to set the desired width on the `TextView` used as the `Spinner`'s row layout instead of `MATCH_PARENT`.

Comment: There's an older question that contains a viable answer (set the weight to 1 for whatever reason): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6543539/spinner-expanding-beyond-screen-bounds